# Смысл БЭМ структура или классы

Tags: html, css, бэм

Есть 2 модальных окна

```
<div class="modal_show_prises">
   <p class="modal_show_prises__text"></p>
</div>


<div class="modal_show_certificate">
     <p class="modal_show_ertificate__text"></p>
</div>
```

оба блока идеинтичны по стилям

Я всегда думал, что переиспользование блоков в БЭМ, это написал код для одного элемента и потом используешь для других элементов, но в моем примере получается что надо пропсывать стили для обоих блоков

Выход есть - назначить более общий класс, например modal, но тогда как в структуре определить что одно окно отвечает за показ призов, второе - за показ сертификатов

```
<div class="modal">
   <p class="modal__text"></p>
</div>


<div class="modal">
     <p class="modal__text"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае можно воспользоваться наследованием и одновременным использованием нескольких классов. То есть более конкретизируя ответ на вашем примере, можно сделать таким образом:

```
<div class="modal show_prises">
  ...
</div>

<div class="modal show_certificate">
  ...
</div>
```

Далее задаете в CSS стиль для класса `modal`, таким образом все `modal` будут наследовать этот стиль, но также вы можете "расширить" описание, путем добавления стилей для `show_prises`, `show_certificate`.

P.S. Если нужно отличать блоки друг от друга, то как вариант каждому можно задать свой `id`, по которому уже можно определить поле.

P.P.S. Также с информацией по классам и использованию нескольких классов можете ознакомиться [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/klassy).

Comment: Работа на карму с отсутствием знаний, норма для сообщества.

Answer (score -2):

Для использования БЭМ нужно прописывать более 1го класса. Конкретно в Вашем случае

```
<div class="modal modal_show modal_show_prises">
   <p class="modal_show_prises__text"></p>
</div>

<div class="modal modal_show modal_show_certificate">
    <p class="modal_show_ertificate__text"></p>
</div>
```

На `modal` можно повесить общие стили и `display: none;`, на `modal_show` - `display: block;`, а разницу на `modal_show_prises` и `modal_show_certificate` соответственно.